# Проблема при копировании объекта класса и высвобождением памяти

Tags: c++, указатели, утечка-памяти

Значит задача была поставленная следующяя(цитирую):

> Необходимо разработать программу, в которой выполняется ввод списка записей определенного типа, а затем - обработка списка. Сначала в программе должен вводиться размер списка (целое число), а сам список создается в виде динамического массива структур. Ввод одной записи осуществляется в одной строке.

Код написал такой , как бы ничего плохого , но при сортировке возникает такая проблема.У нас есть указатель на первый символ строки и при копирование , ну при обмене двух елементов возникает такая проблема , что происходит вызов деструктора и он удаляет ту инфу в памяти , какой являеться строка , ну так как они оби ссылаются на одну и ту же часть памяти.Мне пришлось это исправить и сделал дополнительное поле copy и перегрузил конструктор копирования , но так же не годиться.Как можно по другому избежать данной проблемы?? **Как можно следить за указателям при копировании другим способом???**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
bool fl = 0;
// структура/класс товара
struct Tovar
{
    public:
        bool copy;//копия ли это  , об этом дальше
        char *name = new char[16] , *measurement = new char[6];///указатели на название и меру измирения собственнр
        double price;
        int count;
    public:
        Tovar()
        {
            copy = 0;//"оригинал"
        }
        Tovar(const Tovar& obj)//конструктор
        {
            strcpy(this->name, obj.name);//тут уже по ситуации
            strcpy(this->measurement, obj.measurement);
            this->price = obj.price;
            this->count = obj.count;
            this->copy = 1;//это "копия"

        }
        ~Tovar()//деструктор
        {
            if(copy == 0)//если убрать этот if , то будет ошибка и неприугадоное поведение так как деструктор вызываеться также после создания копий , по этому мы проверяем как была создана переменая , если кто-либо знает как этого избежать поправьте меня
            {
                delete[] name;
                delete[] measurement;
            }

        }
        //удобней выводить//вводить будет так
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& output , const Tovar& obj)//использую friend , чтобы можно было выводит без создания обекта , то есть доступ обычным выводом через поток
        {
            output << obj.name << " " << obj.measurement << " " << obj.price << " " << obj.count << "\n";
            return output;
        }
        friend istream &operator>>(istream& input , Tovar& obj)//тоже самое и здесь
        {
            input >> obj.name >> obj.measurement >> obj.price >> obj.count;
            return input;
        }
};

bool compare_str(char* s1 , char* s2)//Своя функция проверки двух строк , сразу говорю , что если названия товаров начинаються с букв в рахных регистрах , то она не подойдет , также как и стнадартная strcmp
{
    int l1 = strlen(s1) , l2 = strlen(s2);
    for(int i = 0;i < min(l1 , l2);i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] > s2[i])
            return true;
        else if(s1[i] < s2[i])
            return false;
    }
    if(l1 == l2)
        return false;
    else if(l1 > l2)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool func(Tovar a , Tovar b)//comparator(компаратор)
{
    return (!compare_str(a.name , b.name));//из-за особенности STL - сортировки(то есть условие обмена елементов)
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    Tovar* tovars = new Tovar[size];
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        cin >> tovars[i];
    }
    sort(tovars , tovars+size , func);
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        cout << tovars[i];
    }
    delete[] tovars;
}
```

Comment: Особо не разбирался с вашим кодом, но 1) "перегрузил конструктор копирования"... Да, а как вы хотели? Выделяете динамически  память, так следите за указателями. 2) Подумайте над использованием `std::string`.

Comment: Я понял , но вопрос в том , можно ли по-другому без string следит за указателями и высвобождением памяти , например будет указатель на int[] итд...